# Angular ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError inside Dynamic Components

Tags: angular, typescript, directive, angular-changedetection

I am going to resolve components dynamically for different statements.

So, I created one directive and one component for it.

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[mcmsDynamicHost]'
})
export class DynamicHostDirective {

  constructor(
    public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
  ) { }

}
```

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ComponentFactoryResolver, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { DynamicHostDirective } from '@mcms/ui-kit/dynamic-host/dynamic-host.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'mcms-dynamic-host',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-host.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-host.component.scss']
})
export class DynamicHostComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild(DynamicHostDirective) dynamicHost: DynamicHostDirective;

  @Input() component;

  constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.component);

    const viewContainerRef = this.dynamicHost.viewContainerRef;
    viewContainerRef.clear();
    const componentRef = viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
  }

}
```

```
// component template
<ng-template mcmsDynamicHost></ng-template>
```

Now I am using them in this way.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of dashboard">
   <mcms-dynamic-host [component]="item.card"></mcms-dynamic-host>
</div>
```

```
    this.dashboard = [
      {cols: 2, rows: 3, y: 0, x: 0, dragEnabled: true, card: WelcomeCardComponent, title: 'Welcome to Municipal CMS!'},
      {cols: 1, rows: 3, y: 0, x: 2, dragEnabled: true, card: SiteResumeCardComponent, title: 'Site Resume'},
      {cols: 2, rows: 5, y: 3, x: 0, dragEnabled: true, card: TrafficActivityCardComponent, title: 'Traffic activity'},
    ];
```

Static components are rendered without any issue that works.
But if I try to bind some values to template inside dynamically resolved components for example *ngFor or even *ngIf, all throws error - ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

But when I did this trick,

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.data = [
        { image: 'assets/images/green-icons/page-small.svg', title: 'Pages', count: 5 },
        { image: 'assets/images/green-icons/user-small.svg', title: 'Active Users', count: 7 },
        { image: 'assets/images/green-icons/blog-small.svg', title: 'Blog Post', count: 12, pending: 3 },
        { image: 'assets/images/green-icons/comment-small.svg', title: 'Comments', count: 54, pending: 8 },
        { image: 'assets/images/green-icons/media-small.svg', title: 'Digital Assets', count: 230 },
      ];
    }, 100);
  }
```

no errors. It's bit strange for me, anyway we can go with this, but when I try to use for example @angular/material component there's no way to do this kind of trick.

Anyone experieced similar issue?

Here goes stackblitz link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kf3pdw

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the data assignation to the `ngAfterViewInit` lifecycle hook instead of `ngOninit`

By the way, dynamic component loading should usually be done by using the [CDK Portal](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview)

Comment: Yes, right, I have moved code to `ngOnInit` as well. Thanks for the quick reply. Upvoted. Anyway main problem was `static: true` flag of `@ViewChild` decorator.

Answer (score 1):

There was a stupid bug on my code. With Angular v9, @ViewChild decorator static flag default is `false`. This means resolve query result after change detection runs. It should be `true` in order to resolve the query result before change detection runs.

Stackblitz updated with the correct answer. Hope this experience helps others! Cheers!

https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild#description

https://angular.io/guide/static-query-migration